# PHP server raw packet listening

Tags: php, sockets

I need to make a server on php that would write me raw packets (full, not some data parts) send to it... is it possible? Setting out listen port and ip would assume TCP/IP, and won't receive full raw packet... any ideas on how to do it right?

What I basically need is to display full TCP/IP packet with all headers. ALL!

Comment: I smell a man in the middle! :)

Comment: Nah, I need it for different protocol tests... nothing invasive...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of opening a TCP socket, you can open a raw socket.

http://php.net/socket-create

Instead of `SOCK_STREAM` use `SOCK_RAW`.

If you are into linux and you are trying WIFI hacks, install aircrack-ng, setup airmon-ng and listen through this interface (non-blocking benefits) using something like `ngrep mon0`.

`ngrep` tho can be used to watch any interface, e.g. `eth0` (see its manpage).

Comment: `ngrep` is problematic, as it converts known protocol, doesn't display full `tcp/ip` packets for example... how do I divide what I am getting from raw socket into packets?

Comment: @FlashThunder you need to run ngrep with root (almost any tool like that needs root to read raw packets) to be able to capture ethernet traffic of any kind of protocol. ngrep is not limited to tcp/ip.

Comment: It is not limited, but doesn't show whole packet... when it is TCP/IP, it hides it header... and that what's i'm trying to explore... `ettercap` did the job for me...